# What motor controller board is this?

Tags: motor, driver

I was watching a Mark Rober video in which he shows a prototype of his robot, does anyone know what the board in the attached screen-grab is?

[image: Board]

Comment: This is a very low res image. Can you link to the video for more context too? Does he talk about it at all? You have it tagged as brushless so I assume so. Have you tried asking on the youtube video comments or another channel Mark might be watching?

Comment: Link to video..? Please [edit] your question and add the link and/or video title.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found what you're looking for [here on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078TFLD7Q), called "DC Brush Motor Controller, DROK 16A Dual Channel H Bridge Motor Driver Brushed Board DC 5V-36V Motor Drive Control Smart Car PWM Speed Regulator"

I found it by looking at the board in your picture. I counted what appears to be eight beefy-looking transistors, and you mentioned it's for a robot so I assumed they were setup for two H-bridge circuits. Then the connectors on the end look like servo connectors, which are typically PWM, so I googled "Dual H-bridge board with PWM drivers" and found a version online.

Hope this helps! Looks like fun :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @James, that green check mark is always appreciated. Chuck, long the most helpful responder on this site, doesn't need the rep points, but an Accept helps the community find and recognize quality answers.

Comment: @r-bryan <3 Thanks :)